# FQL "X and Y are now friends"

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-friends

I'm trying to get all the recent activity posts where I become friends with another person. Is it possible to retreive the information though the FQL or another way?

I tried to use the stream to the base minimum - by adding a new friend and use the following FQL statement:

select message from stream where source_id = me()

But i don't get the ... are now friends part, can someone tell me how to retrieve such data?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that this info is stored somewhere in a FQL table, at least none that I know of.

The only way I could think of is using the Realtime Updates: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.0

Comment: Thanks for your insight for HTTP callback to Apps, it would be a great feature, but that dons't solve my requirement for my task.

I need to retrieve the past "are now friends" activity. But if its not possible its now possible.. are hoping someone could be me the final answer if it is possible or not.

Comment: To be honest, don't expect that you get many answers one week after your question was posted. At least that's my experience. And I honestly question that the information you want to receive is available. I wish it was though...

Comment: I close this question with the closest answer we can find, that we don't think it's possible in the current state of the facebook api.